# Unable to fetch records in a sharedCloudDatabase custom Zone using CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, cloudkit-sharing

I am trying to fetch CloudKit records from a custom Zone in a sharedDatabase.

The zone has been created correctly during the share process. So I assume that the zone is correctly a shared custom zone (it is indeed in my CloudKit user dashboard, appearing under the sharedDatabase of the default container).

Even with this simple piece of code to retrieve records:

```
func loadRecords() {
    let database = CKContainer.default().sharedCloudDatabase
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Items", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    let zone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "MyCustomZone")
    var fetchedRecords: [CKRecord] = []

    database.perform(query, inZoneWith: zone.zoneID) { (records, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        else if let records = records, let firstRecord = records.first {
            print(firstRecord)
        }
    }
}
```

I keep receiving this error: (sorry was missing in previous post!)

```
<CKError 0x280950840: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Only shared zones can be accessed in the shared DB">
```

Any idea about what I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: Which error? (missing)

Comment: sorry about that, skipped...now updated.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192600/1987726) solves your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am indeed saving the record in the private user DB before the sharing. So the record is saved in private DB, I then share it and the sharing cause the "window" to be generated in the shareDB of the user accepting the share. This is indeed what confuses me...the zone in the shareDB should be indeed shared!

Answer (score 1):

Right, I finally figured it out. Thanks to this additional post here on StackOverflow: [CloudKit Sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603657/cloudkit-sharing)

You indeed have to fetch your custom zone. But it is not enough to give it a name such as "MyCustomZone" because in your shared DB, it becomes MyCustomZone: _acBxxxyyyzzz. A suffix added by CloudKit.

If you don't fetch all your shared zones, you never have the right custom zone from which you need to pickup the record.

Comment: Can you please post the code here that you are referring to? (The fetching shared custom zones etc). Would really appreciate it. Thank you!